# Read from Kafka topic process the data and write back to Kafka topic using scala and spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Hi Im reading froma kafka topic and i want to process the data received from kafka such as tockenization, filtering out unncessary data, removing stop words and finally I want to write back to another Kafka topic

```
// read from kafka
val readStream = existingSparkSession
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", hostAddress)
      .option("subscribe", "my.raw") // Always read from offset 0, for dev/testing purpose
      .load()

val df = readStream.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)" )
df.show(false)
val df_json = df.select(from_json(col("value"), mySchema.defineSchema()).alias("parsed_value"))
val df_text = df_json.withColumn("text", col("parsed_value.payload.Text"))

// perform some data processing actions such as tokenization etc and return cleanedDataframe as the final result

// write back to kafka
val writeStream = cleanedDataframe
      .writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", hostAddress)
      .option("topic", "writing.val")
      .start()
    writeStream.awaitTermination()
```

Then I am getting the below error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> Queries with streaming sources must be executed with
> writeStream.start();;

Then I have edited my code as follows to read from kafka and write into console

```
// read from kafka
val readStream = existingSparkSession
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", hostAddress)
      .option("subscribe", "my.raw") // Always read from offset 0, for dev/testing purpose
      .load()

// write to console
val df = readStream.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)" )
val query = df.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start().awaitTermination();

// then perform the data processing part as mentioned in the first half
```

With the second method, continuously data was displaying in the console but it never run through data processing part. Can I know how can I read from a kafka topic and then perform some actions ( tokenization, removing stop words) on the received data and finally writing back to a new kafka topic?

**EDIT**

Stack Trace is pointing at df.show(false) in the above code during the error

Answer (score 5):

There are two common problems in your current implementation:

1. Apply `show` in a streaming context
2. Code after `awaitTermination` will not be executed

**To 1.**

The method `show` is an action (as opposed to a tranformation) on a dataframe. As you are dealing with streaming dataframes this will cause an error as streaming queries need to be started with `start` (just as the Excpetion text is telling you).

**To 2.**

The method `awaitTermination` is a blocking method which means that subsequent code will not be executed in each micro-batch.

**Overall Solution**

If you want to read and write to Kafka and in-between want to understand what data is being processed by showing the data in the console you can do the following:

```scala
// read from kafka
val readStream = existingSparkSession
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", hostAddress)
      .option("subscribe", "my.raw") // Always read from offset 0, for dev/testing purpose
      .load()

// write to console
val df = readStream.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)" )
df.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start()

val df_json = df.select(from_json(col("value"), mySchema.defineSchema()).alias("parsed_value"))
val df_text = df_json.withColumn("text", col("parsed_value.payload.Text"))

// perform some data processing actions such as tokenization etc and return cleanedDataframe as the final result

// write back to kafka
// the columns `key` and `value` of the DataFrame `cleanedDataframe` will be used for producing the message into the Kafka topic.
val writeStreamKafka = cleanedDataframe
      .writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", hostAddress)
      .option("topic", "writing.val")
      .start()

existingSparkSession.awaitAnyTermination()
```

Note the `existingSparkSession.awaitAnyTermination()` at the very end of the code without using `awaitTermination` directly after the `start`. Also, remember that the columns `key` and `value` of the DataFrame `cleanedDataframe` will be used for producing the message into the Kafka topic. However, a column `key` is not required, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511521/is-key-required-as-part-of-sending-messages-to-kafka/61912094#61912094)

In addition, in case you are using checkpointing (recommended) then you need  to have two different locations set: one for the console stream and the other one for the kafka output stream. It is important to keep in mind that those the streaming queries run independently.