# JMS messages ordering

Tags: ms-access, jms, weblogic, message

I discovered that JMS messages are not delivered in order. This is a great issue for my application.

Searching on the net I've found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252085/how-to-handle-order-of-messages-in-jms) and the [Resequencer class](http://camel.apache.org/resequencer.html) coming from Camel library.

Does anybody know how to use it inside a MDB (Message Driver Bean) hosted by a WebLogic application?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Weblogic supports jms unit of order. Have you seen the docs at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/jms/uoo.html  They even have a youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9J7q5NbXag

Comment: I missed to inform you that the queue is WebLogic Foreign Server linked to an Oracle AQ, so unfortunately I cannot use UOO feature. :(

Answer (score 0):

To ensure order in this cases you almost have to have introduce a sequence. Every time a message is created a sequence is acquired from a sequence object on a database. And when they are consumed on the delivered system the sequence can be taken in consideration when applying the results.
It is almost impossible to 'force' jms to take order in consideration. 
Your application has to do it for you.