# For a single producer and consumer, does JMS queue follow FIFO?

Tags: jms

Does a JMS queue follow FIFO order when there is a single producer and a single consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of message delivery to consumer, FIFO or Priority, depends on the configuration on the queue in a JMS provider. Some JMS providers like IBM MQ, by default deliver messages on priority basis i.e.  higher priority messages are delivered first followed by lower priority. This can be changed to FIFO though. So it basically depends on the configuration.