# What is the best practice to order message working process with JMS

Tags: jakarta-ee, queue, jms, message-queue

I have a task: I want to parallelize message receiving process. The task has thin place: special marked messages must be processed in special order - in order of receiving by my service. I'm trying to solve the task with JMS.
Messages are placing in a queue  and several MessageDriveBeans are processing those messages. I've a "classical requirement": I want to ensure that messages will be processed in same order as they was passed in to the queue. I work with WildFly 8.2 (HornetQ - JMS provider). I know that is a "none of JMS pattern reqirement".

How I can organize this process? Maybe I must to implement another pattern for solving?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle order of messages in JMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252085/how-to-handle-order-of-messages-in-jms)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution. HornetQ (such as WebLogic JMS) provide an ability of message grouping: http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.2.Final/user-manual/en/html/message-grouping.html. Following this opportunity I can established the processing of the same marked messages with the same consumer. Bingo!